# JS using setTimeout and calling set of functions afterwards - DIVI in Wordpress

Tags: settimeout

I'm working on this site using DIVI Framework. The main page has a form that sends to a thank you page, and is what I need help:

I need to set a timeout to send the user to a list of Whatsapp groups by the end of the countdown. Nothing has to show onscreen.

I managed to test and this code works:

```
<script>            
window.setTimeout(function(){ 
location.href = "URL of site" 
}, 5000);
</script>
```

And here is the code that works for sending the person to a random Whatsapp group. I had to put this in a third empty page:

```
<script>
var urls = new Array();
urls[0] = "URL Link to Group 1";
urls[1] = "URL Link to Group 2";
urls[2] = "URL Link to Group 3";
var random = Math.floor(Math.random()*urls.length);
window.location = urls[random];
</script>
```

So I need for both to work together in the same code, on the same page, so I don't need to have that third one, separate.

The logic should be something like:

Countdown starts
By the end of countdown, execute the second part of that script (send to array of groups).

Thanks! :)

Just need to get those 2 to work together.